# Assigning different coefficient names and goodness of fit statistics to different panels in modelsummary

Tags: r, quarto, modelsummary

I am trying to make a table using the modelsummary package in R (thank you to the creator) which has different goodness of fit statistics and names for different panels. I have been unable to achieve this so far. I am working in Quarto.

Here is an example (never mind the validity of the regression). I would like to have the adjusted R squared in the first panel, but not the second. I would also like the coefficients to be renamed as in the coefficient mapping, but this does not seem to be happening.

Very grateful for your help.

```
library(modelsummary)
gm<-tibble::tribble(~raw,~clean,~fmt,
                    "nobs","N",0,
                    "adj.r.squared","Adj. $R^2$",2)

cm <- c("qsec" = "OLS",
        "fit_qsec" = "TSLS")


panels <- list(
  "OLS" = list(
    "(I)" = feols(mpg ~ 1 + qsec, data = mtcars),
    "(II)" = feols(hp ~ 1 + qsec, data = mtcars)
  ),
  "TSLS" = list(
    "(I)" = feols(mpg ~ 1| qsec~drat,data = mtcars),
    "(II)" = feols(hp ~ 1| qsec~drat,data = mtcars)
  )
)

modelsummary(
  panels,
  shape = "rbind",
  cof_map = cm,
  gof_map = gm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question.

First, there’s a typo in your example: `cof_map`.

Second, there’s not a built-in way to use different arguments like `gof_map` in different panels. However, maybe you can hack your way there by using the `glance_custom()` extension mechanism. For this, you’ll need the development version from github:

```r
remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart `R` entirely, then define a `glance_custom.fixest()` which includes a conditional check to delete the `adj.r.squared` value if it meets some condition. Here, we check if this is an instrumental variables model (bottom panel):

```r
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

cm <- c(
    "qsec" = "OLS",
    "fit_qsec" = "TSLS")

panels <- list(
    "OLS" = list(
        "(I)" = feols(mpg ~ 1 + qsec, data = mtcars),
        "(II)" = feols(hp ~ 1 + qsec, data = mtcars)
    ),
    "TSLS" = list(
        "(I)" = feols(mpg ~ 1 | qsec ~ drat, data = mtcars),
        "(II)" = feols(hp ~ 1 | qsec ~ drat, data = mtcars)
    )
)

glance_custom.fixest <- function(x, ...) {
    if (isTRUE(x$iv)) {
        out <- data.frame("adj.r.squared" = NA)
    } else {
        out <- NULL
    }
    return(out)
}

modelsummary(
    panels,
    shape = "rbind",
    coef_map = cm,
    gof_map = c("nobs", "adj.r.squared"))
```

|  | (I) | (II) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OLS | 1.412 | -27.174 |
|  | (0.559) | (4.946) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.148 | 0.485 |
| TSLS | 25.190 | -188.788 |
|  | (47.992) | (328.033) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 | 32 |